# Read nodes inner text by class HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have html like so:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="class1">
        <div>
            <h1> TEXT H1 class 1
                <a> TEXT A  class 1
                </a>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="class2">
    </div>

    <div class="class3">
        <div>
            <h1> TEXT H1 class 3
                <a> TEXT A class 3
                </a>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I got the main class and I was able to iterate through all of the items in it and get what I needed.

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants(0).Where(n => n.HasClass("main"));
```

and inside iteration like so:

```
node.SelectSingleNode("//div/div/h1").FirstChild.InnerText;
```

Then I wanted to get the class3 items so I did this:

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodesClass3 = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants(0).Where(n => n.HasClass("class3"));

foreach(var node in nodesClass3)
{
     var someVariable = node.SelectSingleNode("//div/div/h1").FirstChild.InnerText;
}
```

The iteration for that gives me class ones text and I am not sure why.

I did try to just get the node with class3 alone but unfortunately same outcome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it:

in order to access this node, I should use `.//div/div/h1` not `//div/div/h1`.